# What is the background music played in ep. 2 when we are told of the conquest of Japan?

Tags: music, code-geass

What is the background music played in the first 30 seconds of [episode two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3GBVwZAH6s), when a narrator speaks of the conquest of Japan? This is the section before the OP is played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. It is actually this so:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtxNw8Rs8Ds

Comment: It might be better to add the title of the track (and maybe the source, if you can locate it), in case the video gets taken down in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard all of the OST tracks from Code Geass, and the closest match is in  [Code Geass OST #2 - Pessimistic Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nmOm7qrpDM). If you listen carefully after 0:40, the main instrument's melody is the same. The style and backing are different, but it's normal for there to be some variation between the original OST and the version used in the series itself.

If you want the full list of all songs that played in the series, you can check them [here](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/CDs).

Comment: I skimmed through the link and couldn't find any point that matches up with the segment the OP specifies. (There should be some extended sections involving strings in a somewhat different style, and the oboe? or trumpet? fragment doesn't seem to quite match up either.) Could you perhaps specify where the similarity occurs exactly?

Comment: Because i have heard all of OST's there are from Code Geass, this is the closest to the original music from the 2nd episode. Sometimes you should know there are differences between the original OST and the one that plays on the series. If you listen carefully after 0:40 the main instrument it's 100% the same as the one that start's at the beginning of the episode.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like the main instrument has been replaced, and the style (and backing) is slightly different. Perhaps you could add this detail to your answer (so the situation is clearer to those who are reading more casually)?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't let me edit it (I mean i click the edit button and it doesn't take me to the edit section). Can you please edit that?

Comment: Done with the edit: is this okay? (As an aside: I've also reverted my somewhat careless downvote from earlier: by the time I saw your reply, it was already locked in.)